# suppress line conditional in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-xi

I've a vertical line that i want to suppress with a condition.
Unfortunately I don't see the condition option by a line.
When I use an empty textbox, all the other text is moved down.
Is there conditional  another suppress option for a line?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can't conditionally suppress a line in CR. I know of two options to get around that:

1. Put the line in its own section and then conditionally suppress the section.
2. Put a textbox over the line and then conditionally format the background of the textbox by right-clicking on the textbox -> Format Field -> Border tab -> check Background check box -> click "x+2" box to enter conditional formula, The formula would be something like `if condition then crWhite else NoColor`, where `crWhite` will hide the line, `NoColor` will show it.

Comment: agree with solution 1

Answer (score 1):

Simple way,

1. Insert Text object increase the length of the object as required.
2. Go to Format Object -> select border property and choose Top or bottom lines.
3. Put some text (like under score or space) for object text and minimize the width of the object so that you can't see the provided data to the object but still border appears as a line.

As it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I found an alternative to suppressing a line object, think this might help

```
 CrystalReport1 cr1 = new CrystalReport1();
        (cr1.ReportDefinition.ReportObjects["line_object_name"] as LineObject).LineStyle = CrystalDecisions.Shared.LineStyle.NoLine;
```