# how to suppress first line and third line from a text in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

how to suppress first line and third line from a text in crystal report

e.i

**field=**

```
abcdef
ghijkl
mnopqrs
```

**result will be**

```
ghijkl
```

Comment: abcdef = first line , ghijkl = second line, mnopqrs = third line

Comment: All lines in single section or 3 different sections?

Comment: single section (one field it is a note)

Comment: any option to split this field as three based on lines

Answer (score 0):

There is suppress option you can give via conditionally on field. Check this links, or you can hide the line too.

[suppress line conditional in crystal report](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20485385/suppress-line-conditional-in-crystal-report)

http://scn.sap.com/thread/3373009

http://asad-naeem.blogspot.in/2013/09/conditionally-suppress-line-or-box.html

https://martfish.wordpress.com/2012/03/31/crystal-reports-conditionally-supress-a-line-object/

Comment: any option to split this field as three based on lines

Answer (score 0):

In the supress of the section write below:

```
if recordnumber =1 or recordnumber=3
then true
else false
```

Comment: Thank you shiva. but this formula not solved issue. Because in my case there is no record number. only one field which is bind in report footer. type is string but there will be three or four lines in same field , i want to suppress first and third line only.

Comment: any option to split this field as three based on lines

Comment: how are you showing 3 lines in a single field? what is the formula?

Answer (score 0):

It'll depend on which white space character is separating the lines. This is usually ASCII character 10 (line feed) or 13 (carriage return). In any case you can use the `split()` function to get the line you want.

```
//Returns the second line of a carriage return-delimited text field
split({Table.MultiLineTextField},chr(13))[2]
```

Or, another example:

```
//Returns the third line of a line feed-delimited text field
split({Table.MultiLineTextField},chr(10))[3]
```